# What does 'contrasting views' refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***contrasting views*** refer to? Does it refer to the contrasting moral judgments?

> Everyone talks about the “innovation economy,” but no one knows
> exactly where it begins. If “innovation” means new businesses and new
> ways of working that depend on digital technology, we can trace its
> origins to mid-twentieth-century centers of research and electronics
> production like California’s Silicon Valley and Route 128 in Boston.
> But if we want to know about the current era of “platform capitalism,”
> we look for innovation in new centers of software development in every
> big city of the world, beginning with San Francisco, New York, London,
> and Shanghai. Moral judgments also shape our search. Although critics
> of the new economy are outraged by precarious labor and digital
> surveillance, people who work within the self-styled “tech community”
> prefer an aspirational discourse of “innovation and entrepreneurship.”
> Yet one thing is sure despite ***contrasting views***. Cities today
> are crucial sites for both the creation of — and resistance to — a
> powerful interplay of land, labor, culture, and capital that forms the
> base of the new economy: the “innovation complex.”

[The Innovation Complex: Cities, Tech, and the New Economy](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=OzTNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=Yet%20one%20thing%20is%20sure%20despite%20contrasting%20views.%20Cities%20today%20are%20crucial%20sites%20for%20both%20the%20creation%20of%20%E2%80%94%20and%20resistance%20to%20%E2%80%94%20a%20powerful%20interplay%20of%20land,%20labor,%20culture,%20and%20capital%20that%20forms%20the%20base%20of%20the%20new%20economy:%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinnovation%20complex.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=EHHlJu7705&sig=ACfU3U156_yQTyfmXxMMDAtOF1sdGtNADg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd66SF8JjxAhW2wosBHfDRC4QQ6AEwAnoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Yet%20one%20thing%20is%20sure%20despite%20contrasting%20views.%20Cities%20today%20are%20crucial%20sites%20for%20both%20the%20creation%20of%20%E2%80%94%20and%20resistance%20to%20%E2%80%94%20a%20powerful%20interplay%20of%20land%2C%20labor%2C%20culture%2C%20and%20capital%20that%20forms%20the%20base%20of%20the%20new%20economy%3A%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinnovation%20complex.%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

"*contrasting views*" is what I would call a fancy way of saying

> different points of view.

**contrasting**; adjective; very different: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contrasting)

Comment: Does it cover all the differing views in the passage, or does it refer to specifically moral judgements?

Comment: That I could only guess at, to be honest I find the article poorly written and in my opinion incorrect. The are a lot of very bland assumptions and broad-brush statement that still do not cover the correct areas. He talks about software when he clearly means technology. The focus is world based but the rhetoric is Silcom valley and the credits given to cities whilst many leading Universities are in somewhat more rural locations. As for moral judgements from the way the EU and even Congress are leaning on the tech Giants I do not think they have any.

Comment: Possibly it refers to _both_ different ideas of where the 'innovation economy' started _and_ different opinions as to whether it is 'a good thing' or not.